# mod_rewrite adding unwanted file extension

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-9.04, gentoo

I set up Phorum to use search-engine friendly URLs on my local server (Ubuntu Jaunty). It worked perfectly. Upon moving the site to the production server (Gentoo), I get 404 not found for all pages. The mod_rewrite logs below show the problem.

The same rules are being used on both installs:

```
RewriteEngine On

# READ RULES
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]*)/(.*)$ read.php?$1,$2,$3,$4
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ read.php?$1,$2,$3

RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]*)/(.*)$ read.php?$1,$2,$3
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$ read.php?$1,$2
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$ read.php?$1,$2

# DEFAULT RULES
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)$ $1.php?$2,$3,$4,$5
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)$ $1.php?$2,$3,$4
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-/:\.?]*)$ $1.php?$2,$3
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ $1.php?$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php
```

On my local server the rewrite rule behaves correctly:

```
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (1) pass through /forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-/:\.?]*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list/3 -> list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$' to uri 'list/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] rewrite 'list/3' -> 'list.php?3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) split uri=list.php?3 -> uri=list.php, args=3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add per-dir prefix: list.php -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> /forums/list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b8395ae8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] internal redirect with /forums/list.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /forums/list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /forums/list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-/:\.?]*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php -> list.php
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)$' to uri 'list.php'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:11:32:49 +0100] [home.example.co.uk/sid#b81b3280][rid#b83aa3e8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/] pass through /var/www/mydomain/web/forums/list.php
```

On my production server a file extension suddenly appears - as if the filesystem path has been resolved:

```
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18c3188/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18c3188/initial] (1) pass through /forums/list/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-]*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z=_\-/:\.?]*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] add path info postfix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php -> /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php/3 -> list.php/3
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (3) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)$' to uri 'list.php/3'
88.88.88.8 - - [09/Jun/2009:12:08:21 +0100] [www.example.co.uk/sid#a6b718][rid#18adf78/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/] pass through /var/www/example.co.uk/web/forums/list.php
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) may cause this behavior. Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on, many thanks. I'd vote you up if I could, but don't have permission to do so!

Comment: Thank you!  Exact same problem, -Multiviews fixed it.  Thanks again.